# Internet Explorer run-once resident JavaScript in addon

Tags: internet-explorer, ieaddon

There is a such thing as "background page" in Chrome extensions. It allows to add a kind of run-once code for extension which also sits resident, and then access it from other pages like this:

```
var backPage = chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage();
```

The question is, is there something alike available for Internet Explorer addons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on our experience in extensions for IE we found no way to emulate a *Chrome*-like background page behaviour in IE using JavaScript.